# Churning and subaddresses

Tags: privacy, sub-address, churn

Today I was thinking about churning again. But I was wondering, since we now have subaddresses, does it matter or make any difference when I churn to the main-address or to a subaddress? 
Is one way better than the other or does it not matter at all?

Thanks

Comment: Not so sure why one would churn monero.  Bitcoin, and most others, sure.  Churning it would be more a flag, i'd think. Its like laundering already laundered money a few times.

Comment: Not quite. Whilst churning is less important with Monero than Bitcoin, it does make analysis harder. It also is not a flag. https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-is-churning

Answer (score 3):

Using a main address or subaddress, the result/act of churning is the same.